# Instanciation of OCX Object with Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Hi I'm trying to use an OCX object called "dctl.ocx" in Qt so as to communicate with a numerical Command (Siemens). I followed this page to intergrat it to Qt :
https://blog.actorsfit.com/a?ID=00850-73c6e586-bcc5-4119-95d5-7cdc1bff3d49

And I'm having this error with this code :

Code :

```
_DDctl readObj;
readObj.SetLinkTopic("ncdde|ncu840d");
```

The error :
QAxBase::qt_metacall: Object is not initialized, or initialization failed

I Noticed that this page shows the same problem that I have :
https://forum.qt.io/topic/69584/connecting-to-com-object-requested-control-could-not-be-instantiated

But I already Use , so it doesn't solve my problem

Please help me to find a solution

Comment: Hi Ahmed, is there any way you can post your code or the part of the code that you think may be causing this error. This could be a number of different issues and having some code would help figure out what advice to give.

Comment: Hello sog ! thank you for your interest.

Comment: ```class OCX1LIB_EXPORT _DDctl : public QAxObject
{
public:
    _DDctl(IDispatch *subobject = 0, QAxObject *parent = 0)
    : QAxObject((IUnknown*)subobject, parent)
    {
        internalRelease();
    }```

Comment: If you had a look at the page, you will notice that after applying dumpcpp.exe to the OCX I had .h and .cpp files. the constructor of the class is this code

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not sure I can help you much here because I am having trouble understanding how your error relates to this class description. The only relation I can see is the QT notation. Perhaps you can post your issue to the forum that you have the link to in your original post?